# Which is the best place to write a diary?

Tags: blog

Which internet platforms can be used to write something like a diary?
I am writing on blogger.com, and write at all because:

- I really enjoy writing, since I can do this for hours
- I like to quickly remind myself of what I have been doing in the recent time, during writing

I was writing with my real name and surname some time ago, but I decided to write more anonymously. Currently no one reads my blog.

Can I ask for brief intersection of writing platforms? Do I have to write in libre office, blogger or where is a good place?

Generally I would like someone to read this.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *nayc*! You might be interested in this older question about [What are good places to post your work where it will be read by others?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/904/23159) If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: @Cloudchaser That question is slightly different than this one because this one is about a diary and not stories. I am voting to leave it open.

Answer (score 1):

"Best", of course, is subjective.  However, here are a couple of suggestions.

https://wordpress.com/ is another well known blogging site where users can discover other blogs to read and follow.

https://www.deviantart.com/ has a journal feature, and a surprisingly healthy literature community.